# how to redirect using HTTP_REFERER on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I did my research, but I'm still not able to make this work...

All i'm trying to do is to redirect all incoming traffic from a specific link on another webpage to a page of my choosing...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://theotherwebsite.qc.ca/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://www.cnn.com$ [L]
```

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. RewriteCond needs a regular expression

   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://theotherwebsite\.qc\.ca/ [NC]`
2. RewriteRule needs a regular expression what is should redirect and the target

   `RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.cnn.com [L]`