# .htaccess mod_rewrite.c using HTTP_REFERER

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer

I am trying to get `.htaccess` to fetch the page `http://www.example.org/aa/exists.php` when `http://www.example.org/aa/doesntexist.php` is entered in the URL bar. The `.htaccess` file is clearly functional, because the `DirectoryIndex` line is producing the desired result, with `http://www.example.php` in the URL bar fetching the page `http://www.example.php/aa/default.php`.

I tried adapting the response to [how to redirect using HTTP_REFERER on htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752196/how-to-redirect-using-http-referer-on-htaccess) to my situation, but without success.

Below is the full text of my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)www\.example\.org/aa/doesntexist\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)(www\.example\.org/aa/)doesntexist\.php(.*)$ $1$2exists.php$3 [NC,L]
    DirectoryIndex aa/default.php
</IfModule>
```

A request for `http://www.example.org/aa/doesntexist.php` yields the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL /aa/doesntexist.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Options +FollowSymlinks` and `Allow Override All` as first commands before turning the engine on.

I couldn't see anything wrong in your condition or rule. I recently had a very similar problem that could be solved that way.
If that's not the problem, you might have a look at http://forum.modrewrite.de/topic82.html
It's in German, unfortunately, but maybe stil helpful - at least by aid of google translate (surely not perfect, but good enough).

Btw.: if there is a reason for checking the referrer and not only the requested URI, keep it. Else, the rule alone will do what you want. There is no need for a condition if the content of the condition matches the pattern of the rule.